# Power Query add-in for excel 2010 crashing on load

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to mess around with some dashboard/BI tools since Power BI is no longer free and stumbled upon Power Query/Power Pivot as a potential solution.

I installed Power Query (x32) and am since unable to load excel 2010 when the add-in is enabled. When I disable the add-in Excel opens with no issues. When I re-enable the add-in Excel hangs for a brief moment and then crashes.

I'm running on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with a 32 bit Excel 2010 installation.

Any thoughts as to what could be going on here?

Edit: Many of my coworkers are having a similar issue so it may be something corporate-wide.

Comment: Do you have any other addins installed? Have you tried reinstalling Power Query?

Comment: I haven't tried reinstalling PQ. I'll have to give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had that scenario at one client, and it turned out to be a clash with a specific Add-In - ironically Microsoft's Data Mining Add-In (for SQL 2008 R2).

I suggest first turning on the Developer Main Tab in your Excel ribbon (for convenience) and then using it's **Excel Add-ins** and **COM Add-ins** buttons to disable all other Add-ins besides Power Query.

BTW performance of Power Query on Excel 2010 is truly woeful compared to Excel 2016 (where PQ is also built in, not an add-in).

BTW2 Power BI Desktop and a personal powerbi.com account are both still free.